# When typing 'ls' command I get 'zsh: command not found: gls'

Tags: linux, zsh, ls, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Something strange just happened.

I use iTerm2 and oh-my-zsh on my MacBook and am up-to-date (build 3.0.10 of iTerm2 and current version of oh-my-zsh which I don't know what is). After updating, this happens when typing the **ls** command:

> ls
>
> zsh: command not found: gls

... does anyone know what just happened and how to fix this? I have never heard of **gls** and just simply want my old **ls** back!

### Edit:

For some reason the update made an alias for ls='gls --color=tty', and since I do not have gls, the command was not found. I simply changed the alias to:

> alias ls='ls -G'

(found here: https://superuser.com/questions/183876/how-do-i-get-ls-color-auto-to-work-on-mac-os-x)

and now it works again. Should have figured this out before posting! :)

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your zsh dotfiles? `~/.zshrc ~/.zshlogin ~/.zsh_profile etc.`

Comment: You probably have an alias or function called `ls`. what do you get if you type `type ls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in my edit:

For some reason the update made an alias for ls='gls --color=tty', and since I do not have gls, the command was not found. I simply changed the alias to:

alias ls='ls -G'
(found here: https://superuser.com/questions/183876/how-do-i-get-ls-color-auto-to-work-on-mac-os-x)

and now it works again. Should have figured this out before posting! :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `ls` is simply an alias for the `gls` command, possibly with some default options. So I suggest to type `alias` on your terminal to see all alias definitions. If you find out that `ls` is really an alias, a quick fix could be to execute `unalias ls`.

GNU's Coreutils and the older Fileutils packages contain a `ls` which maybe is expected to be installed under the name `gls` where the g stands for GNU - at least this is the way Darwinports did it. So either you need to install the Corutils package, or maybe your `PATH` environment variable does not contain the path where `gls` is already installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was the problem, I figured that out a few minutes after posting :)

Comment: Homebrew also installs the GNU tools with a `g` prefix.